# plotting multiple plot in R for different calendar date

Tags: r, date, plot, ggplot2

I have about 20 years of daily data in a time series. It has columns Date, rainfall and other data. 
I am trying plot rainfall vs Time. I want to get 20 line plots with different colours and legend is generated that show the years in one graph. I tried the following codes but it is not giving  me the desired results. Any suggestion to fix my issue would be most welcome

```
library(ggplot2)
library(seas)
data(mscdata)
p<-ggplot(data=mscdata,aes(x=date,y=precip,group=year,color=year))
p+geom_line()+scale_x_date(labels=date_format("%m"),breaks=date_breaks("1 months"))
```

Comment: I would advise you to reconsider creating a plot with 20 lines in 20 colors. It wil highly probably look messy. You might want to look into `facet_wrap` or `facet_grid`.

Comment: i know it will look messy  but i would like to do this plot.

Comment: It will not only look messy, but years will overlap and hence only the biggest and most recent years will be visible. Can you explain what it is you are interested in? Dry and wet years? Average rainfall per month?

Comment: I want to see want to see if there is a shift in peaks rainfall. i was going plot 5 years on one graph.. the suggestion provided worked to an extent but i want the legend to be each line represent a year. rather than a colour bar..

Answer (score 1):

It doesnt look great but here's a method. We first coerce the data into dates in the same year:

```
mscdata$dayofyear <- as.Date(format(mscdata$date, "%j"), format = "%j")
```

Then we plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
p <- ggplot(data = mscdata, aes(x = dayofyear, y = precip, group = year, color = year))
p + geom_line() +
    scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%m"), breaks = date_breaks("1 months"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with @Jaap that this may not be the best way to depict these data, try to following:

```
mscdata$doy <- as.numeric(strftime(mscdata$date, format="%j"))

ggplot(data=mscdata,aes(x=doy,y=precip,group=year)) + 
 geom_line(aes(color=year))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Although the given answers are good answers to your questions as it stands, i don't think it will solve your problem. I think you should be looking at a different way to present the data. @Jaap already suggested using facets. Take for example this approach:

```
#first add a month column to your dataframe
mscdata$month <- format(mscdata$date, "%m")

#then plot it using boxplot with year on the X-axis and month as facet.
p1 <- ggplot(data = mscdata, aes(x = year, y = precip, group=year))
p1 + geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = 3) + facet_wrap(~month)
```

This will give you a graph per month, showing the rainfall per year next to one each other. Because i use boxplot, the peaks in rainfall show up as dots ('normal' rain events are inside box).
[image]

Another possible approach would be to use `stat_summary`.